# How do i print the else if none of the if’s is True?

Tags: python

I am trying to print things that you can be eligible for, and if you are not eligible for any of them, I’m trying to print that you are not eligible for any of them. But with this code, it always prints the else along with the if’s

PS: I started programming 1 month ago.

```
print('Task 2')
print()
name = str(input('Navn: '))
age = int(input('Age: '))
gender = str(input('Gender (f for female, m for male): '))
children = int(input('How many children: '))
repute = int(input('repute, on a scale from 1(bad) to 9(immaculate): '))
record = str(input('record (done time/convicted/suspect/clean): '))
seniority = int(input('seniority (years): '))
print()
member = gender == 'f' and age >= 20 and repute <= 7
solder = gender == 'f' and age >= 20 and age <= 30 and repute <= 7 and children == 0
sargent = gender == 'f' and age >= 20 and age <= 30 and repute <= 7 and children == 0 and seniority >= 4 and record != 'clean'
captain = gender == 'f' and age >= 20 and age <= 40 and repute <= 7 and seniority >= 6 and record == ('done time' or 'convicted')
commander = gender == 'f' and age >= 20 and age <= 40 and repute <= 3 and seniority >= 6 and record == ('done time' or 'convicted')
president = gender == 'f' and age >= 20 and age <= 40 and repute <= 2 and seniority >= 8 and record == ('done time' or 'convicted') and name != 'kim'
print('You are eligible to become:')
if member == True:
    print('Member')
if solder == True:
    print('Solder')
if sargent == True:
    print('Sargent')
if captain == True:
    print('Captain')
if commander == True:
    print('Commander')
if president == True:
    print('President')
else: 
    print('You are not eligible to be a member')
```

Comment: use an `elif`s after the first if statement. such that `if False:pass elif True:pass else:pass`

Comment: Have a flag `eligible` and set it initially to `False`. Then for each `if` statement that is True that makes the person eligible to be a member, in addition to printing whatever you do, also set `eligible = True'. Replace your final `else: print('Your are not eligible to be a member')` with `if not eligible: print('Your are not eligible to be a member')`

Comment: Do you want to print only one option for given details or all possibilities? like A soldier is a Member and Solder

Comment: Instead of the final `else`, you need something like this: `if not member or solder or sargent or captain or commander or president:`. As currently written, the `else` only applies to the previous `if`, so it will be run whenever `president` is not `True`.

Comment: Just a tangential note, this part of some of your conditions: `record == ('done time' or 'convicted')` is not going to work the way you think it does.

Comment: @user10987432 Why?

Comment: What you've written does not mean "if record is equal to either 'done time' or equal to 'convicted'". It is evaluated as `record == (True or True)`, which is equivalent to `record == True`. This is because when you evaluate a string by itself as a boolean expression, which is what you're doing, its "truthyness" depends on whether or not the string is empty. An empty string is considered to be Falsey, a non-empty string is considered to be Truthy. What you meant to write is: `record == 'done time' or record == 'convicted'`. Here's an alternative: `record in ('done time', 'convicted')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a final `if` condition to check if none of the conditions matched instead of an `else`:

```
if member == True:
    print('Member')
if solder == True:
    print('Solder')
if sargent == True:
    print('Sargent')
if captain == True:
    print('Captain')
if commander == True:
    print('Commander')
if president == True:
    print('President')
if not (member or solder or sargent or captain or commander or president): 
    print('You are not eligible to be a member')
```

EDIT: Modified to print all eligible positions.

Comment: I believe the OP want's to print all eligible positions.

Comment: Yes, that is what i want.

Comment: Updated with an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

you could replace

```
else: 
    print('You are not eligible to be a member')
```

with

```
if all([not cond for cond in [member, soldier, sargent, captain, commander, president]]):
    print('You are not eligible to be a member')
```

or even with this as comment suggested, using a generator expression, for theoretical better performance

```
if all(not cond for cond in [member, soldier, sargent, captain, commander, president]):
    print('You are not eligible to be a member')
```

Comment: you can write `all([not cond for cond in [member, soldier, sargent, captain, commander, president]])` as `all(not cond for cond in [member, soldier, sargent, captain, commander, president])` so that instead of turning the values into a list it becomes a generator expression

Comment: @dangee can you explain what would the advantage of using a generator expression?

Comment: so for this example in particular it wouldnt actually provide that much of a benefit because of how small the expression is, but lets say you had something like this `all([True for i in range(1000000)])`. what python will do is generate a list containing a million references to `True`, then `all` will check that list too see they are all `True`. If you instead wrote `all(True for i in range(1000000))` instead of making a huge list, the `all` function would generate each `True` as it needed to be checked. This saves a massive amount of memory. Hope this helps :)

Comment: You can also write that as `not any([member, soldier, sargent, captain, commander, president])` or `sum([member, soldier, sargent, captain, commander, president]] == 0`.

Answer (score 1):

Just one more option, So, if you have to add more possibilities, you just insert them in the middle and not have to change any other statement.

```
msg = []
if member:
  msg.append('Member')
if solder:
  msg.append('Soldier')
..
..
if new_possibility:
   msg.append('blah')

if msg:
   print print '\n'.join(msg)
else:
   print 'Not elligible'
```

Comment: This is also a good way to do FizzBuzz. In this case, you probably need to add line breaks after each item though. And `if len(msg):` can be replaced with `if msg:`.

Comment: @MatthiasFripp Right! I don't like \ns, TIMTOWTDI this time with lists! :)

Answer (score 0):

Another options is to use a mapping to determine and print. Allows for modulation.

```
positions = {"Member":member, "Soldier":soldier, "Sargent":sargent, "Captain":captain, "Commander":commander, "President":president}

for i in positions:
    avail_positions = 0 # a counter to determine if we are eligible for anything
    if positions[i]:
        avail_positions += 1
        print('You are eligible to become: {}'.format(i))

if avail_positions == 0:
    print('You are not eligible to be a member')
```